# setUp function is not called before every unit test in python

Tags: python, unit-testing

This is my code that tests the class `School`:

```
class SchoolTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # assertCountEqual is py3, py2 only knowns assetItemsEqual
        if not hasattr(self, 'assertCountEqual'):
            self.assertCountEqual = self.assertItemsEqual
        self.school = School("Haleakala Hippy School")

    def test_an_empty_school(self):
        for n in range(1, 9):
            self.assertCountEqual(set(), self.school.grade(n))

    def test_add_student(self):
        self.school.add("Aimee", 2)
        self.assertCountEqual(("Aimee",), self.school.grade(2))
```

I want to create a new `School` object before every test. When I run the tests, I end up with the following error:

```
    def test_an_empty_school(self):
        for n in range(1, 9):
           self.assertCountEqual(set(), self.school.grade(n))
    AssertionError: Element counts were not equal:
    First has 0, Second has 1:  'Aimee'
```

It means that the second test is called first and the new object is not created, that's why the first test fails.

If I comment any of them and run the tests, it passes regardless of which one I comment.

I feel like I am missing one fundamental thing.

What am I doing wrong?

Just in case, `School` class:

```
class School():
    _db = dict()

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def db(self):
        return self._db

    def add(self, student, grade):
        if grade not in self._db:
            self._db[grade] = set()

        self._db[grade].add(student)

    def grade(self, grade):
        if grade not in self._db:
            return set()

        return self._db[grade]

    def sort(self):
        sorted_list = []

        for grade in self._db:
            sorted_list.append((grade, tuple(self._db[grade])))

        return sorted_list
```

Comment: what is `assertItemsEqual`?

Comment: `self.school` is created indeed

Comment: How are you running the tests?  Have you pasted the _exact_ output in your question?

Comment: @ReutSharabani you can read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertItemsEqual)

Comment: @snakecharmerb I am running the tests like this `py.test grade_school_test.py` and yes! it is the exact output. I copied and pasted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that that `School._db` is an attribute on the *class*, not on an *instance*, so modifications to `School._db` survive between test runs.

You should make _db an instance attribute by initialising it `School.__ init __`

```
class School():

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self._db = dict()
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you very much!